# Application to develop & test asp.net on a mac

Tags: asp.net, macos

I'm starting to learning some asp.net so I'm looking for an application to develop asp.net using a mac.

I know dreamweaver can be used to write asp.net but I don't have any application to run a test server.

Wondering what my options are regarding developing and testing (not on a live server) using a mac.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Download) (available on Mac) would be your best bet for an IDE. Please note that you would be developing for [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX) technically (this is a .NET implementation on non-microsoft platforms).

Keep in mind that the learning curve (coming from Dreamweaver) may be a bit steep in the beginning.

Comment: ChristopheD - you said that to use this tool I would be developing using Mono technically. So I'm guessing that this application just complies projects to run in .NET. Just wondering how this would or could work if I was to be working with existing native .NET projects?

Comment: Hi Adam. Existing ASP.NET projects (websites) targeting the .NET framework 2.0 should be relatively easy to get up and running under mono. Also note that there is only C# support at the moment if I recall correctly. There is useful documentation at mono-project.com. For example have a look at http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_ASP.NET_Applications and http://www.mono-project.com/Start

Answer (score 1):

I use a Macbook Pro to build ASP.NET sites using Windows 7.  It was incredibly easy to setup Bootcamp.  I partitioned 50GB and installed Windows 7.  From there you can install Web Developer Express - http://www.asp.net/vwd/.

The only drawback is I have to go through a kludgy hack to disable the backlight but not sure if you have an desktop or notebook.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Steve, but I should have mentioned that I'm not interested in installing windows on my mac book pro.