# MacBook Pro and ASP.NET applications

Tags: asp.net, macos

Is it ok to develop ASP.NET web applications on MacBook Pro ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application to develop & test asp.net on a mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814378/application-to-develop-test-asp-net-on-a-mac)

Comment: "OK" as in "legally allowed", or as in "possible to do"?

Comment: Sorry if it's duplicate.

Comment: U should really be more specific on if you want to run on windows or the OSX?

Answer (score 4):

.NET is only available for Windows. There's the [Mono project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)), which is not affiliated with Microsoft, which aims to create an open source .NET runtime and developer tools, usable on *NIX (including Mac OS X). If you want to develop .NET applications under **Mac OS**, this is your only choice.

Speaking of a **MacBook** though, you can install Windows on it using Boot Camp or run it in a virtual machine and develop in Visual Studio like on any other Windows box. And this is *ok*, I don't think anybody will confiscate your Mac for doing so.

Comment: You can also install Windows as a guest OS inside VMware or Parallels -- a way to simultaneously run Mac OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows running on the Mac then it is OK.

Another way is to use some .NET IDE for Mac (e.g. [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/))

Comment: I know nothing about Mac OS.
So please more specific.
Is there .net ide for Mac?

Comment: As I mentioned, there is the MonoDevelop IDE that is non-Microsoft product. You can see the link in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

New from Microsoft, IDE for Mac, Linux and Windows: https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

Answer (score 0):

The best method to do that would be to install windows 10 with bootcamp and then install .NET . The steps involved are pretty straight forward. Just open bootcamp and create the partition and select the ISO of windows. Once installed, tap the options key on boot to boot to windows. If everything is smooth, you can continue the development, else, just open bootcamp again and delete the partition.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10 - open this on mac to get the legal windows image. This will be valid only for a limited time